# lex|flex rule action ignored

Tags: callback, lex, flex-lexer

All,

I have  a specified type of pattern in my lex file:

```
 "#"[ \\t]*"ifdef".*                { action_ifdef_manager(yytext);}
```

if a text like this encoutred `#ifdef GLOBALVAR` the action `action_ifdef_manager` is not called

Thanks for any Help.

Comment: It’s almost impossible to answer your question without some context.  Obviously, if that was the only rule in your lexer, action_if_def_manager should be called, but that’s probably not the case.  Try simplifying your lexer sources to make a minimal example where you still observe the problem.

Comment: @ArthurReutenauer i think that the problem does'nt come from an ambiguity of rules in my lexer, indeed the '.*' at the end of the pattern push the lexer until finding a '\n' witch is a pattern in my lexer so '\n' 's action is called.

Comment: I’m not sure I understand you right, but isn’t that precisely an ambiguity in your lexer?  Or rather, the way you designed it is ambiguous, and Flex resolves this in a way you didn’t expect.  Anyway, if the newline character is the problem here, it may be enough to exclude it from the rule, for example by using '[^\n]*' instead of '.*'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only problem is ambiguity of patterns. You should have a similar pattern like '#ifdef'

```
          a        |
          ab       |
          abc      |
          abcd     ECHO; REJECT;
```

The lexer here returns in "abcd" stream all four validated patterns a , ab , abc, abcd

Take a look at [the Flex manual](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Actions.html)